# When I one hot encode a column with corresponding values. It gets null values in between them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping, one-hot-encoding

I hope this finds you all well. I have been working with a steel data-set. I was trying to one_hot_encode a categorical data column with their corresponding values using mapping method. However when I do this the column gets null values in between. I am unable to understand why. The column before one_hot_encoding did not have any null values. However, after mapping with the corresponding values it gets null values in between. Here is the code:

```
df["material_spec"].unique()
array(['Material_0', 'Material_1', 'Material_2', 'Material_3',
       'Material_4', 'Material_5', 'Material_6', 'Material_7',
       'Material_8', 'Material_9', 'Material_10', 'Material_11',
       'Material_12', 'Material_13', 'Material_14', 'Material_15',
       'Material_16', 'Material_17', 'Material_18', 'Material_19',
       'Material_20', 'Material_21', 'Material_22', 'Material_23',
       'Material_24', 'Material_25', 'Material_26', 'Material_27',
       'Material_28', 'Material_29', 'Material_30', 'Material_31',
       'Material_32', 'Material_33', 'Material_34', 'Material_35',
       'Material_36', 'Material_37', 'Material_38', 'Material_39',
       'Material_40', 'Material_41', 'Material_42', 'Material_43',
       'Material_44', 'Material_45', 'Material_46', 'Material_47',
       'Material_48'], dtype=object)
```

This is how I am one_hot_encoding the data:

```
df["material_spec"] = df["material_spec"].map({"Material_0":0, "Material_1":1,"Material_2":2,"Material_3":3,"Material_4":4,"Material_5":5,
                                              "Material_6":6,"Material_7":7,"Material_8":8,"Material_9":9,"Material_10":10,"Material_11":11,"Material_12":12,
                                              "Material_13":13,"Material_14":14,"Material_15":15,"Material_16":16,"Material_17":17,"Material_18":18,"Material_19":19,"Material:20":20,"Material_21":21,"Material_22":22,"Material_23":23,"Material_24":24,"Material_25":25,"Material_26":26,"Material_27":27,"Material_28":28,
                                              "Material_29":29,"Material_30":30,"Material_31":31,"Material_32":32,"Material_33":33,"Material_34":34,
                                             "Material_35":35,"Material_36":36,"Material_37":37,"Material_38":38,"Material_39":39,
                                              "Material_40":40,"Material_41":41,"Material_42":42,"Material_43":43,"Material_44":44,
                                              "Material_45":45,"Material_46":46,"Material_47":47,"Material_48":48})
```

And this results after this mapping:

```
df["material_spec"].isnull().sum()
122
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here. Is my way of one hot encoding wrong or is it due to some other error? Any suggestions would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: from your map dict : `"Material:20":20`

Answer (score 0):

@ansev has answered your immediate question in the comments.

Here's another way to do what you want to do that may be easier for you:

```
df["material_spec"].str.extract(r'Material_(\d+)').astype(int)
```

But what you are doing is not really one-hot encoding is it?  I think of one-hot encoding to be more like this:

```
df["material_spec"].str.get_dummies()
```

Comment: I am basically trying to map these strings to their corresponding numbers so that I can have numeric values of these columns before feeding them to the machine learning model.